# Filtering dates obtained from monthdatescalendar gives AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'weekday'

Tags: python, list, datetime, calendar

**Scenario:** I am trying to pass all days of a month to a list, in which I could iterate and use functions on the days, such as weekday().

**Issue:** So far, I was able to use Calendar to pass dates or days into a list. In both cases, when I try to read the dates and output only the wanted weekday, I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'weekday'
```

**What I did so far (with the help from other posts here on SO):**

This here works fine, but I need it to be more dynamic

```
import calendar
cal = calendar.Calendar()
cal.monthdatescalendar(2019, 1)[0][1]
cal.monthdatescalendar(2019, 1)[0][1].weekday()
r = [foo for foo in cal.monthdatescalendar(2019, 1)]
```

**So I tried:**

```
r = [foo for foo in calendar.monthcalendar(2019, 1)]
list(r)
```

**and**

```
r = [foo for foo in cal.monthdatescalendar(2019, 1)]
list(r)
```

**All of these work fine, but when I try to iterate, like:**

```
r = [foo for foo in cal.monthdatescalendar(2019, 1)]
if r[1].weekday() == 1:
    list(r)
```

**or**

```
r = [foo for foo in cal.monthdatescalendar(2019, 1) if foo[1].weekday() == 1]
list(r)
```

I get the previously mentioned error.

**Question:** Any Idea on how to do this properly / more efficiently?

**Final objective:** Is to create a function that takes as input month, year, week and weekday, and returns me a datetime object.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand something but what's the point of this line: `r = [foo for foo in cal.monthdatescalendar(2019, 1)]` if you could just write `r = cal.monthdatescalendar(2019, 1)`?

Comment: @Georgy I was trying to create something I can iterate later with a condition. That line, without the "if" statement, was just a test. The main objective is in: r = [foo for foo in cal.monthdatescalendar(2019, 1) if foo[1].weekday() == 1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably something like this

```
import calendar

cal = calendar.Calendar(firstweekday=0) # firstweekday is an integer specifying the first day of the week. 0 is Monday (the default), 6 is Sunday.
for my_date in cal.itermonthdates(year=2019, month=1):
    print('{}. Weekday is {}'.format(my_date.strftime('%A, %Y-%m-%d'), my_date.weekday()))
```

or if you want to use monthdatescalendar, in which case you will gate list of list, i.e. list ot weeks and each week is also a list

```
import calendar

cal = calendar.Calendar(firstweekday=0) # firstweekday is an integer specifying the first day of the week. 0 is Monday (the default), 6 is Sunday.
for week in cal.monthdatescalendar(year=2019, month=1):
    for my_date in week:
        print('{}. Weekday is {}'.format(my_date.strftime('%A, %Y-%m-%d'), my_date.weekday()))
```

Note that it will expose full weeks, e.g. in this case it will start with 31 Dec 2018.

Comment: Thanks, itermonthdates allows me to use the weekday() attribute. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that [`monthdatescalendar`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html#calendar.Calendar.monthdatescalendar) returns a nested list:

```
>>> import calendar
>>> cal = calendar.Calendar()
>>> cal.monthdatescalendar(2019, 1)
[[datetime.date(2018, 12, 31),
  datetime.date(2019, 1, 1),
  datetime.date(2019, 1, 2),
  datetime.date(2019, 1, 3),
  datetime.date(2019, 1, 4),
  datetime.date(2019, 1, 5),
  datetime.date(2019, 1, 6)],
 [datetime.date(2019, 1, 7),
  datetime.date(2019, 1, 8),
  datetime.date(2019, 1, 9),
  datetime.date(2019, 1, 10),
  ...
```

So, if you want to keep the same structure, in order to retrieve only second days of the week, you could do the following:

```
>>> filtered_month = [[day for day in week if day.weekday() == 1]
                      for week in cal.monthdatescalendar(2019, 1)]
>>> filtered_month
[[datetime.date(2019, 1, 1)],
 [datetime.date(2019, 1, 8)],
 [datetime.date(2019, 1, 15)],
 [datetime.date(2019, 1, 22)],
 [datetime.date(2019, 1, 29)]]
```

Another option is to use [`itermonthdates`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html#calendar.Calendar.itermonthdates) but the list will be flat:

```
>>> [day for day in cal.itermonthdates(2019, 1) if day.weekday() == 1]
[datetime.date(2019, 1, 1),
 datetime.date(2019, 1, 8),
 datetime.date(2019, 1, 15),
 datetime.date(2019, 1, 22),
 datetime.date(2019, 1, 29)]
```

Also, note that you can specify the first day of the calendar when creating a [`Calendar`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html#calendar.Calendar) object. Then to obtain the first days of the week, you just have to take the first elements of the lists:

```
>>> cal = calendar.Calendar(calendar.TUESDAY)
>>> [week[0] for week in cal.monthdatescalendar(2019, 1)]
[datetime.date(2019, 1, 1),
 datetime.date(2019, 1, 8),
 datetime.date(2019, 1, 15),
 datetime.date(2019, 1, 22),
 datetime.date(2019, 1, 29)]
```

**P.S.:**
As a side note, I think it's better to compare days explicitly like this:

```
if day.weekday() == calendar.TUESDAY:
    ...
```

instead of

```
if day.weekday() == 1:
    ...
```

Because [*Explicit is better than implicit*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/#id3).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually the last part is very interesting because it could account for the problem of dates from other months bleeding into the list. Problem is, I want to keep the code flexible, so if I set the weekday start with ((calendar.TUESDAY)) I would run into the problem if I input other months or years directly.